# Mysql Remove newline, nullcharacter, and LineFeed QUICKLY

Tags: mysql

i have a table with 20,085,250 rows in it, and some guy let a \n, \r, and, \0 get mixed in the middle of the table while it was being populated. it takes 10 seconds just to do SELECT count(*) FROM Table, so it is huge.

I need to replace all of these characters with nothing. i have been able to do it with just one column in 2.5 years. i have 10 columns that i need to do this with, and it is on a production server where i cannot have the table locked in an update query for 2.5 years. my current query looks like this

```
UPDATE Table set `column1` = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(`column1`, '\r', ''), '\n', ''), '\0', '');
```

Does anyone have any good idea how to speed this behemoth up?

Comment: You could do it incrementally by using a WHERE condition to limit the updated rows to a specific subset of rows. Ex: `id BETWEEN 1 AND 1000000`, then `id BETWEEN 1000001 AND 2000000`, and so on... Though, if you are expecting this data cleanup to speed up `SELECT COUNT(*)` queries, I think you'll be disappointed.

Comment: no i dont want to speed up the count just speed up the update

Comment: perhaps this is my only option?

Comment: how static is the data?  does it change often?  perhaps create a new table by selecting these values instead of updating them.. then at the end replace the current table with the corrected values.

Comment: well it is not static at all every time someone logs in or changes pages it logs the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found out that i should just try and update all 10 columns at once, because apparently MySQL's biggest overhead is just bring up the row, after it is there doing stuff to it is easy. so i just updated all 10 at once, and the whole thing runs in just under 2.5 minutes. i know this is not ideal, but it is the best solution i found.